# Connecting to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

```
$dbh = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root','');

/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = TRUE; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

/* User for advanced features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

/* Advanced phpMyAdmin features */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';

/*
```

Hey guys. Im getting an error when I try to connect to my database on phpmyadmin.  Im not sure why its denying access.  Anyone know why this is happening ?

Comment: Seems pretty self explanitory. Have you checked that the root user exists without a password?

Comment: @scrowler how do I do that (im new to this stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Go to phpmyadmmin

type

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

At the top of page 4th tab is users. Click on it and you will see a simple table containing the names and privileges of all users on db server